# How do I insert multiple copies of an integer into the middle of a list?

Tags: python, list

My assignment is this:

Let `L` be a list of non-negative integers. Write an expression that replaces the centermost element of `L` with that many copies of `0`. Note that "centermost" here is defined the usual way for a list of odd length, but may seem a bit unusual for a list of even length. So, for example, if `L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, the modified value of `L` will be `[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5]`, but if `L = [1, 2, 0, 3]`, the modified value would be `[1, 2, 3]`, as the `0` – here the centermost element of an even-length list – would be replaced with 0 copies of `0`.

The expression I came up with is

```
L[len(L)/2] = [0] * L[(len(L)/2)]
```

and output for `L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` is

```
[1, 2, [0, 0, 0], 4, 5]
```

I need to eliminate that inner list element such that the zeroes are part of the outer list. We are restricted to a single line and no for/while loops.

Comment: Try a slice.  That's too short, so I'll say it again.  Try a slice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Python 2.3, it is possible to [assign to slices](https://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html):

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> L[len(L)//2:len(L)//2 + 1] = [0] * L[(len(L)//2)]
>>> L
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5]   
>>> L = [1, 2, 0, 3]
>>> L[len(L)//2:len(L)//2 + 1] = [0] * L[(len(L)//2)]
>>> L
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

As @saulspatz suggests use slicing:

```
middle = len(L) / 2
L = L[:middle] + ([0] * L[middle]) + L[middle + 1:]
```

Comment: and this can obviously be done in one line per your requirements by not using the variable middle, and just using len(L)/2 where it appears. To read more on slicing I find this question super helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation

Comment: Actually, I meant "assign to a slice" as ekhumoro did in his answer, but this works too, of course.

Comment: I never knew this was possible. Thanks :-)